# nodejs jade load links from config

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, pug, config

Im using nodejs with jade. Its awesome *.*

Ok. But now I have a Question. Is it possible to load all links for `<a href='/link'>` from a config-file so I can easiely edit them?

If it is possible, please say me how :D

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require JSON files

config.json:

```
{
    "link_home" : "/",
    "link_news" : "/news"
}
```

server.js:

```
var config = require('./config.json')
...
res.render('index', {config: config})
```

layout.jade

```
...
li: a(href='#{config.link_home}') home
...
```